# Windows Forms - How to display Update/Cancel Button in DataGridViewButtonColumn?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

When I develop ASP .NET Web Applications, I use the following code to show `Update` and `Cancel` buttons when a user clicks on `Edit` button inside DataGridView Column.

```
<asp:EditCommandColumn EditText="Edit" 
             ButtonType="LinkButton" 
             UpdateText="Update" 
             CancelText="Cancel" 
             HeaderText="Update"/>
```

Is there any way to do it in Windows Forms? What I have planned to do now is I will add three `DataGridViewButtonColumn`s `Edit`, `Update` and `Cancel`. And on cell click event of DataGridView, `Edit` column will be hidden and `Update` and `Cancel` Column will be displayed.

Another solution is to use `DataGridViewLinkCell`  and change the value of the column after clicking on the cell.
Example: [Insert, Update & Delete Table from DataGridView in C#.Net](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/238727-insert-update-and-delete-records-in-table-with-datagridview-using-c#/)

There are a lot of questions on SO asking about DataGridView Select/Insert/Update/Delete Commands. But I'd like to know which will be the suitable method to use in this situation. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this & perform operations as you want :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            displayDataGridView();  

            DataGridViewButtonColumn EditBtn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            EditBtn.HeaderText = "Edit";
            EditBtn.Text = "Edit";
            EditBtn.Name = "EditBtn";
            EditBtn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(EditBtn);  

            DataGridViewButtonColumn DeleteBtn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();  
            DeleteBtn.HeaderText = "Delete";  
            DeleteBtn.Name = "DeleteBtn";
            DeleteBtn.Text = "Delete";  
            DeleteBtn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(DeleteBtn);  

        }
```